# Linux CMake Error for not finding an ODE library

Tags: linux, cmake

I am currently working for a school project team planning to participate in the [RoboCup competition](https://ssl.robocup.org/), and for it  I need to install a program called [grSim](https://github.com/RoboCup-SSL/grSim) on Linux. I followed [the installation instructions](https://github.com/RoboCup-SSL/grSim/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and should have installed all the dependencies as the instruction tells me to, but when I try to run `cmake ..`, my grSim package it shows me the error:

```
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find ODE (missing: ODE_LIBRARIES ODE_PRECISION) (found version
  "")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindODE.cmake:32 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (find_package)
```

Which simply means that cmake could not find the ODE library, which I should already have installed by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install ... libode-dev ...
```

according to the instruction. I am new to Linux. My other teammates just simply followed the install instructions and installed the grSim program with no problem. My Linux is newly installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `GrSim/INSTALL.md` recommends Ubuntu 14.04. I tested with Ubuntu 16.04.5 : `$ cd GrSim/  && make` : No issues.

But `sudo make install` complains : " ... No package 'ode-double' found" ... "Could NOT find ODE (missing : ODE_PRECISION)" ... and some text about "path to ode-double.pc".

Solution :

```
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
$ sudo cp ode.pc ode-double.pc
```

And `$ cd GrSim/ && sudo make install` now works OK.

---

P.S.: No issues "Could NOT find ODE" with Ubuntu 14.04.5 . And the GrSim GUI opens OK with `$ grSim` on Ubuntu 14.04 .

PPS : Ubuntu 18.04 → Fix "Could NOT find ODE" with 'sudo cp ode.pc ode-double.pc, and GrSim compiles OK ... and the 'grSim' GUI opens OK.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your time and I haven't responded because I was busy with school. Unfortunately, I tried your method in Ubuntu 18.04 but it did not work for me. ODE is still missing. I did "ls" in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/" and "ode.pc" and "ode-double.pc" are present, but grSim still shows "no ODE found". Am I doing something wrong? Once again thank you !

Comment: Eventually, I gave up on installing the application on Ubuntu 18.04 but instead I just used 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions that I searched worked, so just use release version "v2.2": https://github.com/RoboCup-SSL/grSim/releases/tag/v2.2

Apparently this is an error after the commit "Improve FindODE.cmake"